# Is \$I_e = I_c\$ for phototransistors?

Tags: current, phototransistor

Due to the base current, in a common emitter circuit the emitter current is a bit higher than the collector current:

\$ I_e = \dfrac{1+\beta}{\beta} I_c \$

I was wondering how this is for a phototransistor, like in an optocoupler. I would expect emitter and collector current to be equal because there is no base current. But a photodiode can create a current with zero volt across it, so it seems the photons can create electrons. So is \$I_e = I_c\$ for phototransistors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be; there is nowhere else for the charge to go.

Photons don't create electrons; they create electron-hole pairs. The electron is accelerated to the collector, the hole to the emitter (for NPN phototransistors; opposite for PNP ones).

In a photodiode, some of the electrons and holes end up on opposite sides of the barrier and can't easily recombine until (a) they build up a voltage of about 0.5V to attract them back across or (b) you provide an easier external current path. This is turning into quite a big industry...

Comment: *What* is turning into quite a big industry? Shoveling electrons? :-)

Comment: shoveling electrons through photodiodes!

Comment: I don't get it.  Photodiodes can most certainly generate a current, even at zero volts if reverse biased appropriately, and thus provide a base current in a phototransistor.

Answer (score 4):

Of course \$ I_e = I_c \$ for a phototransistor.
Anything else would violate [Kirchhoff's current law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws).

Answer (score 2):

Both of the other answers are right, but I suspect you're getting a little confused.  Yes, there is energy (photons) going into the base, and yes those photons create a current in the base which is acted upon by the Hfe of the transistor to control the C/E current.  That base current will be reflected in an increased C/E current flow because it has to flow through there.  But that increase will be **tiny** in comparison to the main current flow.  There isn't current flow from your circuit into the base, the photo-transistor is still a two terminal device with respect to your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems the photons can create electrons

Photons don't create new electrons. Photons make the already existing electrons move. In this particular case, when a photon collide with an electron, photon increases kinetic energy of the electron. Then, the electron moves from base to emitter. This physical phenomenon creates a pseudo base current which turns the transistor on.